# Can I open a program in a certain resolution?

Tags: arch-linux, kde, resolution

I run Arch on my Steam Deck with KDE. Most of the time my deck is hooked up to my TV with a much higher resolution than the Deck. When I try to watch movies in Jellyfin or VLC it always launches the application on the main screen at the tiny resolution while I'd want it to start in 4k.

I'm thinking that there might be for example a flag or something I'd set like `--resolution=1920x1089` but that seems to be very dependent on the application in question. Maybe writing a short bash script would be simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my issue by using Steams functionality to set non-steam game resolutions and then in Jellyfin Media Player's settings to always launch in full screen.